# php variable in style (width) attribute

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a php echo, and I would like to use a variable for the width attribute to avoid needing an if statement. I tried to use this code:

```
<?php echo variable; ?>
```

It didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: (Variable)'>";
```

Comment: Are you aware that variables in php begin with `$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work:

```
echo   "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: ".$variable."'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$variable = "10px";
echo   "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: $variable'>";
```

Works when you use the "-string

Answer (score 1):

Do not echo the html only echo the variable:

```
<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: <?php echo $variable?>px'>;
```

Notice that I also added px after echoing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $variable=100'; ?>

echo   "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='25' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: ( ".$variable.")'>";
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score 1):

and if you wanna be more fancy you can check if the variable is not empty:

```
<?php if($variable != ""):?>
<!-- this will be the output if variable has some value -->
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $variable; ?>px">

<?php else: ?>
<!-- some default value -->
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100px">

<?php endif;?>
```