# Simple Question: Using a php variable and px in an echo <style>?

Tags: php, css

I am learning PHP and I am trying to echo a style for a shape. The problem I have is that I am trying to have the user input a measurement in a html text field which then turns into PHP variable using the get method. All of this works fine until I try to use the variable in the style with px. I tried...

```
echo "width: $length + 'px';"
echo "width: $length'px';"
echo "width: $length + "px";"
```

..and I just can't figure it out. I am sure this a seems like a silly question and answer; however, I already did some google searches and could't find the answer. Thank you to all replies.

Comment: Could you please provide more code, do you want just to display the value or are you doing something with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php variable in style (width) attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229915/php-variable-in-style-width-attribute)

Comment: Change `echo "width: $length + 'px';"` to `echo "width: {$length}px;"` (called string interpolation). If you want to use concatenation instead, use `echo "width: " . $length . "px;"`. [Read more in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for your reply {$length}px worked great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
echo "width: " . $length . "px;";
```

For concatenate strings in PHP you have to use "."

Comment: This did work and I do understand now why it worked. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want you can use `echo "width: {$length}px;";` too, but personally I prefer concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Various possibilities:

[**Interpolation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

```
echo "width: {$length}px;";
```

<sub>(Normally you wouldn't need the curly braces around `$length` for this, but you do in this case because there's no space between the number and the px, so PHP will think you're referring to a variable called `$lengthpx` if you don't use them.)</sub>

[**Concatenation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#language.operators.string)

```
echo "width: " . $length . "px;";
```

[**Formatted print**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf('width: %dpx;', $length);
```

[**Multiple arguments to `echo`.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

```
echo "width: ", $length, "px;";
```